# Filter results for instagram videos only- instafeed.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, instafeedjs

I am using the great and dead simple `instafeed.js` to pull a couple of my instagram videos into my personal webpage. It is working but I have not found an option for filtering results for just videos. Currently it shows a combination of images and videos. All I want for the return result is videos.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var feed = new Instafeed({
     limit: '10',
     sortBy: 'most-liked',
     resolution: 'standard_resolution',
     clientId: '467ede5a6b9b48ae8e03f4e2582aeeb3', 
     template:'<div class="tile"><div class="text"><b>{{likes}} &hearts; </b>{{model.user.full_name}}</div><img class="item" src="{{image}}"></div>'
  });
</script>

<div id="instafeed"></div>
```

Comment: @StevenSchobert it seems that you are developer for this. could you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `filter` option:

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
  limit: '10',
  sortBy: 'most-liked',
  resolution: 'standard_resolution',
  clientId: 'xxxxx', 
  template:'<div class="tile"><div class="text"><b>{{likes}} &hearts; </b>{{model.user.full_name}}</div><img class="item" src="{{image}}"></div>',
  filter: function(image) {
    return image.type === 'video';
  }
});
```

This will run each `image` through that function. The function will then check to see if `image.type` is `video`. If it's not, the function returns `false`, which tells Instafeed.js to exclude that image from the results.

*Note: Make sure you are using at least v1.3 of Instafeed.js, which included the filter option.*

Comment: Perfect, Imagine i can also do vice versa for images only. Could i filter for location as well?

Comment: Yes, you could do `return image.type === 'image';` to get only images! You can filter by locations as well, though it'll take a little more code, since Instagram returns locations as geo-coordinates. Hope that helps!

Comment: Great! could i return a numeric value of `image.type === 'video'`?

Comment: What do you mean by "return a numeric value"? Are you trying to count how many total videos are being shown?

Comment: Please see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701197/limit-with-filter-instafeed-js