# Limit with filter - instafeed.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, instafeedjs

I am using the great tool of `instafeed.js` to interact with instagram’s api. I am currently trying to filter results to only be `image.type === 'video'`. I have been able to get that to work. The only problem is that it never satisfies the `limit:10` set. Somehow it may be pulling all types(`image` and `video`) and then applying the filter.  Is it possible to meet the limit `10` while applying a filter for videos only?

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
  limit: '10',
  sortBy: 'most-liked',
  resolution: 'standard_resolution',
  clientId: 'xxxxx', 
  template:'<div class="tile"><div class="text"><b>{{likes}} &hearts; </b>{{model.user.full_name}}</div><img class="item" src="{{image}}"></div>',
  filter: function(image) {
    return image.type === 'video';
  }
});
```

Comment: @StevenSchobert Another help here please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the `filter` is always applied *after* the `limit` option.

To get around that, try setting the `limit` to a higher number, then removing extra images after the fact:

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
  limit: 30,
  sortBy: 'most-liked',
  resolution: 'standard_resolution',
  clientId: 'xxxxx', 
  template:'<div class="tile"><div class="text"><b>{{likes}} &hearts; </b>{{model.user.full_name}}</div><img class="item" src="{{image}}"></div>',
  filter: function(image) {
    return image.type === 'video';
  },
  after: function () {
    var images = $("#instafeed").find('div');
    if (images.length > 10) {
      $(images.slice(10, images.length)).remove();
    }
  }
});
```

You can also check [this thread](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/8) on Github for more details.

Comment: Still yields below the number 10.

Comment: Do you have less than 10 videos in your last 30 posts? You may also try setting the limit to -1.

Comment: it shoots an error with `limit: -1`. You can check this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bullseye2346/gkavx7md/)

Comment: Where you able to check my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bullseye2346/gkavx7md/). `Limit: -1` yields an error.

Comment: Multiple Tags - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948807/instafeed-js-feed-display-more-then-one-tag

Comment: could you please look at the question above?